# What's a word used for someone who criticizes his country but doesn't let any foreigner criticize his country?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, american-english

I noticed some people attack foreigners who say anything negative about their country, yet they themselves criticize their same country and are being negative. What's a word that describes them? Looking for a word that doesn't have a political connotation. Other than hypocrite.

Comment: Perhaps "hypocrite" is the word you're looking for?

Comment: How is this hypocritical? Whether it is or not, it's pretty universal.

Comment: Is this related to how only members of a group can criticize it?  Like "entitled"?

Comment: “Normal”. Have you ever lived abroad? Ask a psychologist for an explanation.

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/hypocrite

Comment: I have lived in my adopted country longer than the majority of its citizens have, and yet even my wife feels offended when I criticize some cultural attitudes. On the other hand, when I hear people from here criticize the US, I also feel my hackles rise even though I usually agree agree with them  (and believe me., that happens quite a bit). It seems to be a normal type of patriotic feeling that is more or less universal. Moreover, I have also seen it extend to residents of different states, and even towns.

Comment: @tk421 No. let's say you're American. You criticize stuff in the US. A non American does the same and you become defensive about the US and try to refute his points even though you know what he is criticizing is valid. This happens online like in discussion forums or Facebook groups.

Comment: @Hot As I said, I am looking for a word other than 'hypocrite'. A word that shows the person's love and passion for his country at the expense of being honest about all his opinions and being impartial.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich - It's a link to a thesaurus -- a list of (near) synonyms.  Did you go through the list?

Comment: I think 'flag-waver' or 'nationalist' are a bit closer.

Comment: If I were not so lazy I would post an answer, but it sounds like the "us vs. them mentality"

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is one word that encompasses both attitudes. [Patriotism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patriotism) may lead nationals to frown upon external criticism and, indirectly, to their feeling that they are the only ones empowered or entitled (as @tk421 cleverly suggested) to speak as they wish about their domestic affairs.

This issue reminds me of a famous, long poem from my country, "Martin Fierro", which refers to the question in the following words:

> Brothers should stand by each other because this is the first law.
>
> Keep a true bond between you always, at every time --
>
> because if you fight among yourselves you'll be devoured by those outside.

(Translated from Spanish by [Kate Kavanagh](http://martinfierroenglish.blogspot.com/2015/03/the-best-translation-of-martin-fierro.html))

Answer (score 0):

*"Don't talk about matters you don't know!"* ~ This is a very common sentence we hear now and then. And what you are describing is not hypocrisy in any way. **It's a psycological concept** and sadly has not specific term in the current dictionary.

If you live in a particular country A, you are the citizen, you are the one who voted for the system, you are the one suffering from the problems the nation is facing. But someone who lives thousands of miles away from you and has never visited your country has no right to critize it. They didn't vote for the system, they aren't experiencing what the citizens are. People don't like people to interfere in their personal matters when they can't change anything. It's like you fight with your siblings but if some stranger tries to harm them, you take your sibling's side. Look, at last your country is the only place which will help you, he's not inviting you to his country. **So, it's just a psycological concept which unfortunately has no terminology in English.**